# Magnifying Glass Is Missing In My Textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a textview embedded in my `tableviewcell`. The problem is when I long-press the `textview` it doesn't show the magnifying glass.

I've had this problem for several days - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in `appDelegate.m` add the following code:

```
self.window.windowLevel = 1.2;
```

Comment: I tried but the problem remains still,though  i'm able to  double-click to call out the popup menu,